# JPA does not save property in MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, reactjs, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am learning Spring boot right now and I am using it as a backend and I am using React as a frontend.

I am saving data via JPA Hibernate every property is getting saved properly but the team_name is not getting saved and I do not know why it is not getting saved, I hope you can help me out with this.

My MySQL table player has 4 properties:
id is the primary key, age,name, team_name as foreign key

Then the MySQL table Team has one property name which is the primary key. And as you can see in the Java code player and team are in a relationship.

And when I can log the this.state.team property it gives me the team name, it is not null, it is just not getting saved in the MySQL table.

Updated code:

Java Player Entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Player {

    @Id
    private String id;


    private String name;
    private String age;

    @ManyToOne 
    @JsonBackReference
    private Team team;


}
```

Java Team Entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Team {

    @Id
    private String name;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team")
    private List<Player> players;

}
```

React code:

```
class Player extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            player:{},
            playerName: null,
            id:null,
            flag:null,
            age:null,
            team:null,
            name: null
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.getPlayerData = this.getPlayerData.bind(this)
    }

    async getPlayerData(playerName){
        const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";    
        const url = "https://www.hltv.org/search?term=" + playerName
        const fullUrl= proxyurl+url
        const response = await fetch(fullUrl)
        const arr = await response.json()
        const player = arr[0].players[0];
        const fullName= player.firstName + " " + player.lastName


         this.setState({
            playerName: player.nickName,
            id: player.id,
            flag: player.flagUrl,
            age:null,
            team:{
                name: player.team.name
            },
            name: fullName

        })
    }

    async createNonExistingTeam(){
        const teamData={
            name:this.state.team.name
        }

         await fetch("/api/team" , {
            method: 'POST' ,
            headers : {
              'Accept' : 'application/json',
              'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(teamData)
        })
    }

    async createNonExistingPlayer(){
        const data={
            id: this.state.playerName,
            age: null,
            name:this.state.name,
            team_name: this.state.team.name
        }
        await fetch("/api/player" , {
            method: 'POST' ,
            headers : {
              'Accept' : 'application/json',
              'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        await this.handleSubmit()
    }


    async handleSubmit(event){
        const {playerName} = this.state


            try{
                const response =  await fetch(`/api/player/${playerName}` , {
                    method: 'GET' ,
                    headers : {
                      'Accept' : 'application/json',
                      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                    }})
                const output = await response.json();
                this.setState({
                    player:output
                })
            } catch(e){

                await this.getPlayerData(playerName)
                await this.createNonExistingTeam()
                await this.createNonExistingPlayer()

            }

        const style = {
            marginTop: 20,
            marginLeft: 30
        }

        const {player} = this.state
        const {playerData} = this.state
        const {flag} = this.state
        const {id} = this.state



const picLink = "https://static.hltv.org//images/playerprofile/bodyshot/compressed/" + id + ".png"
        const data = 
        <div>
            <PlayerData
                style={style} 
                ign={player.id}
                name={player.name} 
                pic={picLink}
                nation={flag}
                age={player.age}

            />

        </div>



        ReactDOM.render(data,document.getElementById('playerData'))


}





    async handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    }
```

EDIT Controller code:

PlayerController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class PlayerController {

    @Autowired
    private PlayerRepository playerRepository;

    @GetMapping("/players")
    List<Player>getAllPlayers(){
        return playerRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/player")
    ResponseEntity<Player> createPlayer(@Valid @RequestBody Player player) throws URISyntaxException{
        Player result = playerRepository.save(player);

        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/player" + result.getId())).body(player);
    }

    @GetMapping("/player/{id}")
    ResponseEntity<?> getPlayer(@PathVariable String id){
        Optional<Player>result =  playerRepository.findById(id);
        ResponseEntity<Player> resMap = result.map(response->ResponseEntity.ok().body(response)).orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
        return resMap;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{name}/players")
    List<Player> findPlayers(@PathVariable Team name){
        return playerRepository.findByTeam(name);
    }
}
```

TeamController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TeamController {

    @Autowired
    private TeamRepository tRepository;

    @PostMapping("/team")
    ResponseEntity<Team> createTeam(@Valid @RequestBody Team team) throws URISyntaxException{
        Team result = tRepository.save(team);

        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/team/" + result.getName())).body(team);
    }


    }
```

EDIT:

I realized that when I print my player in the create player method in Java the team is showing as NULL so I guess I have a problem in my POST request.

Comment: Provide the controller with the service layer, please.

Comment: @Nikolas Is that necessary for this request? It is not really doing something

Comment: If you debug the `createPlayer` controller method can you see correct team value?

Comment: @Rohit Yea when I log it, I get the correct value but it is just not getting saved in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is not correct and you can remove the @Table annotation because this is 
redundant.

You also shouldn't use @Data annotation because this may cause a StackOverflowError with bi-directional references.

First use @ManyToOne instead of @OneToOne:

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Player {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;
    private String age;

    @ManyToOne 
    @JsonBackReference
    private Team team;
}
```

Then you must use the mappedBy attribute to tell JPA that there is a back reference:

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name="team")
public class Team {

    @Id
    private String name;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team")
    private List<Player> players;
}
```

Comment: But one player can only have one team, is this still possible like this?

Comment: What so ever I tried those changes and still the team_name is not getting saved in the MySQL table

Comment: You should show the controller code as someone else suggest to see how you map the request to the Entiteis

Answer (score 0):

Your front end `Player` component does not represent the `Player` and `Team` entity relationship.

It should be:

```
{
    playerName: player.nickName,
    id: player.id,
    flag: player.flagUrl,
    age:null,
    team:{
            name:player.team.name
        },
    name: fullName
}
```

Comment: Perhaps because of the missed comma before name.I corrected it now. In the REST controller createPlayer method `Player` has `Team` correctly populated?

Comment: No syntax error anymore but the team_name row in my  MySQL table is still empty

Comment: Is the JSON received form the FE corrrectly deserialized to `Player` object in your backend?

Comment: `@PostMapping("/player")
    ResponseEntity<Player> createPlayer(@Valid @RequestBody Player player) throws URISyntaxException{
        //If you log the player here, does it contain the team.
        Player result = playerRepository.save(player);

        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/player" + result.getId())).body(player);
    }`

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean but when I save my player via POST request the properties name and id in my MySQL table are filled in correctly but the team_name stays empty

Comment: when I log it I am not getting the team:      
Player(id=Xyp9x, name=Andreas Højsleth, age=null, team=null) that is the sysout print in Java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211869/discussion-between-cimbomlu1905-and-rohit).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem. I figured out that I had a mistake in my POST request. I changed my getPlayerData method to this:

```
this.setState({
            playerName: player.nickName,
            id: player.id,
            flag: player.flagUrl,
            age:null,
            team:{
                name: player.team.name
            },
            name: fullName
            })
```

And in my POST request, I made a new variable.

```
const dat={
   name: this.state.team.name
}
```

And changed my data object like this:

```
const data={
            id: this.state.playerName,
            age: null,
            name:this.state.name,
            team: dat
        }
```